# Prove the sum of 2 Bernoulli is binomial

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

let $X_1,X_2$ be independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with parameter p ∈ (0, 1).Prove that the sum $Y=X_1+X_2$ of these random variables is a binomial random variable with parameters 2 and p

Comment: Hi! Although I am not the right one to help you with this question, I'll give you a friendly remainder - questions on this site (especially asking for proof/solution) are better accepted, when you also post what you've tried, not just the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1, X_2$ are two iid Bernoulli random variables, then their sum is the count of successes in two iid Bernoulli experiments.   This is the *definition* of a binomial random variable  with parameters $2$ and $p$.

That is all. $\Box$

---

If you need to demonstrate further:

The probability that there will be exactly $y$ successes among these two variables is determined by measuring the probability of $y$ successes in a row followed by $2-y$ failures, then multiply this by the count of distinct ways to order these results.

That is:
$$\mathsf P(Y=y) = \underline{\qquad\qquad?}$$

Which was to be demonstrated. $\Box$

---

Alternatively, from first principles we use the Law of Total Probability to show that when we partition the results by the first variable:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y=y)
 &= \mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=y-1) + \mathsf P(X_1=0, X_2=y)
\\[1ex]& = p\cdot \mathsf P(X_2=y-1) + (1-p)\cdot \mathsf P(X_2=y)
\\[1ex]& = \begin{cases}
 \underline\qquad & : y =0
\\ \underline\qquad & : y=1
\\ \underline\qquad & : y=2
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Which was to be demonstrated. $\Box$

---

Fill in the blanks if required.  But really, you don't need to go passed the first tombstone.

Answer (score 0):

The range of the random variable must be $\{0,1,2\}$.  You have to show the probabilities of the three values is the same.  So just calculate the three probabilities of a binomial with parameters $2$ and $p$ and do the same for the sum of two Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$ and you'll see the three probabilities are the same in both cases.  So they are the same random variable.

Comment: can you prove that?

Comment: Prove what? If two random variables have the same 'point mass function' (or 'probability distribution function', depending on the text), then they are considered to be the same random variable. It surely would be helpful if we had a clue what level probability course this is. For example, have you studied moment generating functions? Bivariate distributions?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Thank you, I guess he wants me to actually do the calculations.  I'll do that later if I get a minute.